# Strange error message when assigning Swift function with arguments to Objective-C property

Tags: swift, objective-c

I would like to set some properties of an Objective-C class instance to some Swift functions and I am getting an error that I do not understand, maybe something with the types is wrong:

Objective-C:

```objectivec
@interface MyWrapper : NSObject
@property (nonatomic) void(*f1)();
@property (nonatomic) void(*f2)(void*);
@end
```

Swift:

```swift
func saySomething1() {
    print("Something 1")
}

func saySomething2(buf:UnsafeRawPointer) {
    print("Something 2")
}

let x = MyWrapper()
x.f1 = saySomething1 // OK
x.f2 = saySomething2 // error: Cannot assign to property: 'x' is a 'let' constant
```

Changing `let` to `var` does not help (same error message).

Comment: Wild guess: since pointer can change, what if you change it to `Mutable` pointer type, e.g. `UnsafeMutablePointer` (`func saySomething2(buf:UnsafeMutablePointer)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not the mutability of the variable `x` (it is a class type, anyway), but rather of the parameter for `f2`. Use `UnsafeMutableRawPointer`, rather than `UnsafeRawPointer`.

---

FWIW, if you are unsure of the parameter type, you can open the assistant editor and then look at the generated Swift interface:

[image: generated interface]

You access this from the jump bar in the assistant editor:

[image: jump bar]

Or you can use a closure and type inference can tell you what type the parameter is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot. Besides using the right type, the adding of NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_BEGIN / NS_ASSUME_NONNULL_END did it.

One more question: How do I generate the above Swift interface from the .h file? I opened the assistant, but could not find where to generate it.

Comment: You access it from the jump bar in the assistant editor. See animated GIF in my revised answer. The above is in Xcode 12.4.